# debugging python setup.py for an open source library - bcfg2

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py, pypi

When I install `bcfg2` - http://bcfg2.org using

```
pip install git+git://git.mcs.anl.gov/bcfg2.git#egg=Bcfg2
```

or

```
pip install bcfg2
```

I am able to get `bcfg2` working. Calling `sudo bcfg2-admin init`, shows me the set-up configuration steps/stdin prompt as expected.

When I introduce the `-e` option like this (in a new/clean virtualenv),

```
pip install -e git+git://git.mcs.anl.gov/bcfg2.git#egg=Bcfg2
```

And I attempt to call `sudo bcfg2-admin init`, I get an error message:-

```
calvin$ bcfg2-admin init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/bcfg2/bin/bcfg2-admin", line 7, in <module>
    execfile(__file__)
  File "/Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/bcfg2/src/bcfg2/src/sbin/bcfg2-admin", line 6, in <module>
    import Bcfg2.Server.Core
ImportError: No module named Bcfg2.Server.Core
```

This leads me to think that there is something wrong with the way `setup.py` is written for `bcfg2`.  The file is located here - https://github.com/Bcfg2/bcfg2/blob/master/setup.py

Appreciate any input from pythonistas who are experts with python packaging and the configuration of setup.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setup.py` has a bug.

Figured it out, fixed it and sent a pull request to `bcfg2` maintainers.

Reference - https://github.com/Bcfg2/bcfg2/pull/28

Answer (score 0):

You've installed to a virtual environment (`-e`). However when you run this with sudo python gets executed as root without the virtual environment available.

If you run `sudo su` you should be dropped into a root shell. You can then activate the virtual environment and run bcfg2-admin.

Comment: correction: my description above is wrong.  my mistake. there isn't a `sudo` in front.  Just doing `bcfg2-admin init` gives me the exact same error.